# How can I "split" a table using EF Core 6.0 to participate in two different relationships?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, class-table-inheritance, ef-core-6.0

I need to add 'notes' to multiple entities in my EF Core 6 data model. Notes have exactly the same schema - a date/time, the name of the person who created the note, and a comment - so I'd like to use a single database table, with a discriminator column on each `Note` record which indicates which relationship/entity it belongs to.

My entity model looks like this:

```cs
public class Note {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set;}
  pulic string CreatedBy { get; set; }
  public string Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm trying to map the appropriate properties on my `DbContext` to produce this set of tables:

```
Notes
+----+------------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------------------------+
| Id | EntityType | EntityId | CreatedAt        | CreatedBy  | Comments                         |
+----+------------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------------------------+
| 1  | Customer   | 17       | 2022-01-22T18:22 | alice      | Cancelled erroneous invoice      |
| 2  | Supplier   | 19       | 2022-01-23T12:52 | bob        | Amended booking date to April    |
| 3  | Customer   | 24       | 2022-01-24T19:07 | bob        | Refunded duplicated order        |
| 4  | Customer   | 17       | 2022-01-27T18:22 | alice      | Added Bryan Smith as contact     |
| 5  | Supplier   | 22       | 2022-01-27T20:17 | carol      | Override booking terms for 2022  |
+----+------------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------------------------+


Customers
+----+------------------+
| Id | Name             |
+----+------------------+
| 17 | Fisher Price Plc |
| 24 | Bob's Bikes Ltd  |
+----+------------------+


Suppliers
+----+-------------------------+
| Id | Name                    |
+----+-------------------------+
| 19 | Wigs'r'Us International |
| 22 | Monkeys Unlimited       |
+----+-------------------------+
```

Anybody know what combination of properties, entities and discriminators I can use to get this working?

I've tried creating a `SupplierNote` and `CustomerNote` class, which inherit from `Note`, and then mapping them like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Note>()
  .HasDiscriminator<string>(note => note.EntityType)
  .HasValue<CustomerNote>(nameof(Customer))
  .HasValue<SupplierNote>(nameof(Supplier));
```

but this creates a `Note` table with `CustomerId` and `SupplierId` columns, which isn't what I'm after.

Comment: Then you treat it as like a pair of M:M and have a CustomerNotes and SupplierNotes table to mediate between a customer/supplier and all their notes.. To find what a note belongs to you have to query two tables though; with a TPH style Notes with SupplierId/CustomerId where one is blank you only have one. Compromises

Comment: *which isn't what I'm after* - but are you *really* bothered how EF stores it?

Comment: You will need to create two derivative classes `CustomerNote : Note` and `SupplierNote: Note` each which has their own binding to the type. You can even make a generic derivative type, although that might be over engineering. Both will be combined in one `Note` table, as by default EF used a table-per-hierarchy ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration)).

Answer (score 1):

> Anybody know what combination of properties, entities and discriminators I can use to get this working?

I know for sure that no such combination exists currently (up to the latest at this time EFC 6.0 inclusive).

What you are seeking for is called *polymorphic association*, and is *not* supported by any EF (classic or Core) version. Because EF supports only associations which can be represented by physical enforced FK constraint in relational database.

Shortly, it's not possible. The simplest you could do though is to revisit the *"I'd like to use a single database table"* and just use separate tables. Multiple tables maintained by EF Core migrations are basically no cost. You can map your common class as owned entity and use it as collection of owned entities mapped to different tables in the entities which need it. Or you can try to map it as the EFC 5.0 introduced *shared entity type*. Or you can use it as a base *class* (not *entity*) and create and use concrete entity classes derived from it with no additional members. In all the cases, they would be mapped to separate tables, but their content will be defined/maintained in one place and also could be queried/manipulated polymorphically against the base class (of course except instance creation).

If you really want to stay with that db model, then you can't use navigation properties and must query/maintain them manually. And wait if someday (if any) EF adds support for logical relationships/navigations.

Comment: "EF supports only associations which can be represented by physical enforced FK constraint in relational database which apparently do not apply to these."

When you put it like that, it's suddenly very obvious why what I'm trying to do is not supported. Thank you :)

Comment: @DylanBeattie I'm not native English speaker, so sorry if something I wrote sounds offending - that's not the intent. Feel free to edit it out. Other than that, whatever we say, the unfortunate reality is that it can't done. I was just trying to add more "rationale" why. Happy coding.

Comment: No, not at all - your explanation was genuinely very helpful. The thing I'm trying to do is a pattern I've seen used a lot in the past, and so I'd sort of forgotten that it's not actually a strict relational model - and as you pointed out, EF Core only supports associated that can actually be enforced in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create two derivative classes `CustomerNote : Note` and `SupplierNote: Note` each which has their own binding to the type. You can even make a generic derivative type, although that might be over engineering. Both will be combined in one `Note` table, as by default EF used a table-per-hierarchy ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration)). This will add a discriminator to the table.

```cs
namespace EFExample
{
    public abstract class NoteBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Note<T> : NoteBase
    {
        public virtual T Owner { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Note<Customer>> Notes { get; set; } = new();
    }

    public class Supplier
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Note<Supplier>> Notes { get; set; } = new();
    }
}
```

The context will just have three enities

```cs
        public DbSet<NoteBase> Notes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
```

adding is a bit verbose this way, so maybe `SupplierNote` is not a bad idea

```cs
    context.Add(new Supplier
    {
        Notes = new List<Note<Supplier>> {
            new Note<Supplier>
            {
                CreatedBy = "Me",
                Comments = "Hello",
            }
        }

    });
    context.SaveChanges();
```

[image]